# Why do jQuery icons not get aligned with text-align CSS property?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I'm using some of the jQuery UI icons as a column headers in a table. The spans do not align based on the text align property and I haven't been able to find a reasonable workaround.

I've tried using both the `text-align` property in CSS and the `align` property of `th` and the icon span will not center. Instead it keeps left aligned.

**HTML**

```
<th align="center" scope="col" style="width:100px;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RuleGrid','Sort$5')"><span class="ui-state-default ui-icon ui-icon-locked"></span></a></th>
```

**CSS**

```
th
{
    text-align:center;
}​
```

I've got a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2NBrd/) to depict the problem.

Comment: Try text-align: center; on the span itself

Comment: @DavidBélanger `text align center` on the span doesn't work either. I tried that as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to only be an issue in IE, chrome and firefox rendered it correctly.
You can remove the span tag and just put the classes onto the a tag instead. I just added the style "margin: 0 auto" and it fixed the issue in IE.

Cheers.

```
<th scope="col" align="center" style="width:100px;">
    <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('RuleGrid','Sort$5')" class="ui-state-default ui-icon ui-icon-locked" style="margin:0 auto"/>
</th>
```